# forzar cambio de contraseña al iniciar sesion por primera vez

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, login

estoy realizando un login por PHP, que te solicite cambiar la contraseña al iniciar sesión por primera vez (no tendrá opción de registrarse, por lo que yo brindare el usuario y contraseña) tengo 4 archivos que es el flujo del código index, login,  first_sesion , sesion

login.php (ese código lo que realiza es la conexión con la base de datos consultando las columnas que se va a necesitar para la interfaz de la pagina y en caso que la columna sesión sea 1 me redirigirá a first sesion

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3307;dbname=intranet', 'root', '');
    
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT usuario.nombre, usuario.apellido, puesto_trabajo.puesto, usuario.permisos, usuario.sesion FROM usuario INNER JOIN puesto_trabajo ON usuario.puesto = puesto_trabajo.id_puesto WHERE usuarios = :user AND contraseña = :password');
    
    $stmt->bindValue(':user', $user);
    $stmt->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    if ($result) {
        // Las credenciales son válidas
        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $result['nombre'];
        $_SESSION['apellido'] = $result['apellido'];
        $_SESSION['puesto'] = $result['puesto'];
        $_SESSION['sesion'] = $result['sesion'];
        // Verificar si se debe mostrar la página de cambio de contraseña
        $showChangePassword = $result['sesion'] === 1;
    
        if ($showChangePassword) {
            // Redirigir a la página de cambio de contraseña
            header('Location: first_session.php');
            exit;
        } else {
            // Redirigir a la página principal después del inicio de sesión exitoso
            header('Location: inicio.php');
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        // Autenticación fallida, redirigir al usuario al formulario de inicio de sesión con un mensaje de error
        header('Location: index.php?error=1');
        exit;
    }
```

first_sesion(acá realiza la actualización del cambio de la contraseña por una ventana emergente)

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['new_password'])) {
        $new_password = $_POST['new_password'];
        try {
            $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=database', 'username', 'password');
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE usuario SET contraseña = :new_password, sesion = 1 WHERE usuarios = :user');
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':new_password' => $new_password,
                ':user' => $_SESSION['sesion']
            ));
            header('Location: index.php');
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        echo '<form method="post">
                <label for="new_password">Nueva contraseña:</label>
                <input type="password" name="new_password" id="new_password">
                <input type="submit" value="Cambiar contraseña">
              </form>';
    }
} else {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
```

sesion.php (acá se verifica si el usuario realizo el cambio de contraseña o no)

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    
    if ($result) {
        // Las credenciales son válidas
        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $result['nombre'];
        $_SESSION['apellido'] = $result['apellido'];
        $_SESSION['puesto'] = $result['puesto'];
        $_SESSION['permisos'] = $result['permisos'];
    
        // Verificar si se debe mostrar la ventana emergente de cambio de contraseña
        $showChangePassword = $result['sesion'] === 1;
    
        if ($showChangePassword) {
            // Redirigir a first_session.php para mostrar la ventana emergente de cambio de contraseña
            header('Location: first_session.php');
            exit;
        } else {
            // Redirigir a session.php
            header('Location: inicio.php');
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        // Autenticación fallida, redireccionar al usuario al formulario de inicio de sesión con un mensaje de error
        header('Location: index.php?error=1');
        exit;

}
```

Cuando inicio sesión, me redirige nuevamente a login, como si en vez de iniciar sesión se actualizara la pagina y no me deja ingresar al inicio.

Comment: Hola Lil, ¿será que tenes que cambiar `sesion = 1` por `sesion = 0` en el `UPDATE` que haces en el `first_sesion`?

Comment: ya realice ese cambio y aun sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Si pones la estructura de la tabla y de si puedes el primer form, puedo replicar tu escenario y ver que encuentro. Estaré pendiente....

Answer (score 0):

Es más sencillo de lo que estás intentando hacer

Vas hacer una consulta de esta manera

```
$_SESSION['sesion'] = $result['sesion'];
        // Verificar si se debe mostrar la página de cambio de contraseña
    
        if ($result["sesion"]===0) {
            // Redirigir a la página de cambio de contraseña
            header('Location: first_session.php');
            exit;
        } else {
            // Redirigir a la página principal después del inicio de sesión exitoso
            header('Location: inicio.php');
            exit;
        }
```